# Column reference is ambiguos Error postgresql

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun_obtenerloginropa(IN character varying(20), IN ppassword character varying(20))
  RETURNS TABLE(rlogin character varying(20), rpassword character varying(15),rropa character varying(5), rproveedor character varying(50))

LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN



    RETURN QUERY 

    SELECT A.login, A.password , A.ropa, A.proveedor FROM users A WHERE A.login = plogin AND password = ppassword;

END;
$function$;
ALTER FUNCTION fun_obtenerloginropa(character varying(20), character varying(20))
OWNER TO sysprogsrcompras;
```

Me aparece ese error al momento de mandar a llamar esta funcion, entiendo que es por la columna login pero pense que agregandole el alias a la tabla (select A.login) se corregiria el problema pero sigo sin poder mandar a llamar a la funcion

Comment: ¿Solo eso te dice?. ¿Estás seguro que hay una sola funcion fun_obtenerloginropa? (porque a veces se generan varias, porque si cambian los parámetros es otra función). Si pusieras en tu pregunta el código completo del error más los detalles que aparezcan mejor (por ejemplo haciendo la llamada directa desde el pgAdmin o psql). También estaría bueno tener la definición de la tabla. Así te vamos a poder ayudar mejor.

Comment: Es probable que este reclamando por algún parámetro, que se llame igual que alguna columna, acostumbrate a referenciar los parámetros con $N, pero de todos modos analiza si existe otra funcion con el mismo nombre...